# how to use same script for 2 ID on same page?

Tags: html, slidedown

I have a liking script that get ID from php and insert id to data base then the script shows the result by ID. I use same html code and same script for differents Ids but siledown result open on first div id instead of  the ont that i click it:

HTML:

```
    <a href="javascript://" class="like" sta_id="1" username="{S_USERNAME}" title="Like">Like</a>
<div id="sn_likebox">
<span id="close"><a href="javascript://" class="close" title="Close This">X</a></span>
<div style="height:13px">
<div id="flash">Loading........</div>
</div>
<div id="sn_like_content">
</div>
</div>
<p>----------------------------------</p><div></div>
<p>-----------------------------------</p><div></div>
<a href="javascript://" class="like" sta_id="2" username="{S_USERNAME}" title="Like">Like</a>
<div id="sn_likebox">
<span id="close"><a href="javascript://" class="close" title="Close This">X</a></span>
<div style="height:13px">
<div id="flash">Loading........</div>
</div>
<div id="sn_like_content">
</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(".like").click(function()
{
var sta_id=$(this).attr("sta_id");
var username=$(this).attr("username");
var dataString ='sta_id='+ sta_id + '&username='+ username;
$("#sn_likebox").slideDown("slow");

$("#flash").fadeIn("slow");


$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : us_cfg.url,
data: dataString,    
cache: false,


success: function(html)
{
$("#flash").fadeOut("slow");
$("#sn_like_content").html(html);
}
});

});





$(".close").click(function()
{
$("#sn_likebox").slideUp("slow");
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ke5AB/112/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two [identical IDs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) on the same page. Use a different selector type (such as a class).

Comment: thanks for your answer, Im not using identical ID, if you see my demo im using diferent id for it and my php code creates multiple id for it, on my example i included sta_id=1 and sta_id=2 ..thanks!

Comment: @user1133401 - Your example does have two DIVs with the ID of "flash", and your script references "#flash". Am I missing something?

Comment: those div's are for html code only, the one that i'm trying to use its (sta_id="1") and  ("sta_id="2) the sta_id="" its created by php code, if include the code once on my html page it works great but including second one if i click on it it pull data from database but it slidedown into first one.

Comment: @user1133401-I am happy to help you and so I feel obligated to point out that Tim Medora *is* 100% correct, if you don't fix the issue of PHP rendering two HTML elements with identical ID's you will have problems.  I realize that the solution to your problem may be in a different area, but you have to fix this issue as well ;).

Comment: Ok, I got it now! What you guys mean its that i have to work with php code to create different Ids for its divs! thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can't place two elements with the same ID in the DOM.  You need to make them unique, then your code will work with them.

Comment: I'm sorry but im new working with this, can you give me an example please?

Comment: No need to apologize.  I think that maybe you are referring to "sta_id" rather than "id".  If that is the case, you probably need to prefix that tag in your HTML with "data".  So you would have "data-sta_id=1".  See if that helps.  I have to run for the night but will check in the morning if you got the help you needed.  Good luck!